# Pandas Merge | Missing Values on Inner Join, extra Values on Outer

Tags: pandas, merge, inner-join, missing-data, outer-join

Trying to merge two Dataframes on an identical  ID-Column, same name and all values are present in both DF, same Datatype. However, doing an inner join on the ID Column results in only around 12000 of around 78000 rows:

```
DataFrame_1
0   itemID      78030 non-null  int32  
1   title       78030 non-null  object 
2   cluster     78030 non-null  object
+
DataFrame_2
0   itemID      78030 non-null  int32  
1   title       78030 non-null  object 
2   cluster     78030 non-null  object


MergeDf = pd.merge(DF1,DF2,how='inner', on='itemID')

0  itemID        12753 non-null   object
1  title_x       12753 non-null   object 
2  title_y       12753 non-null   object 
3  cluster_y     12753 non-null   object 
4  cluster_y     12753 non-null   object
```

Do the IDs actually exist ?

```
DF1['itemID'].isin(DF2['itemID']).value_counts())
True     78030
False    0
```

The 12753 rows seem to be the ones were the inner join works and were the ID Values seem to match.

```
MergeDf = pd.merge(DF1,DF2,how='left', on='itemID')

 0  itemID        78030 non-null  object  
 1  title_x       78030 non-null  object 
 2  cluster_x     78030 non-null  object 
 3  title_y       12753 non-null  object
 4  Cluster_y     12753 non-null  object
```

Only the same 12753 were accepted from column Y.

```
MergeDf = pd.merge(DF1,DF2,how='outer', on='itemID')  


0  itemID        143307 non-null  float64
1  title_x       78030 non-null   object 
2  title_y       78030 non-null   object 
3  cluster_y     78030 non-null   object 
4  cluster_y     78030 non-null   object
```

There are 143307 rows now, 78030 with title/cluster X values, the same amout for Y, a part of these are the 12753 that have values for both and are included in both sets.

78030 - 12753 = 143307, so 12753 is the part of the DataFrame that is somehow shared and looking also at the csv output has both X and Y columns.

What might be the cause of this, I need 78030 of title/cluster X/Y in one DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

With pandas merge, merging on outer will keep all columns and rows from both dataframes. As you noticed, merging on the ID will still include duplicates.

With the dataframe merging that I just did, I had to merge on multiple columns.

So in your example...

```
0  itemID        143307 non-null  float64
1  title_x       78030 non-null   object 
2  title_y       78030 non-null   object 
3  cluster_y     78030 non-null   object 
4  cluster_y     78030 non-null   object
```

You see that 78030 shows up for multiple cluster_y column values. If you were to write something like... (fill in the header for the cluster_y column header)

```
MergeDf = pd.merge(DF1, DF2, how='outer', on=['itemID', 'cluster', '(..whatever else)'])
```

This will merge on ID and then if that ID has some cluster in common, it will merge on that, and so on.